# How to return values from group_by in R dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Good morning,

I've got a two-column dataset which I'd like to spread to more columns based on a group_by in Dplyr but I'm not sure how.

My data looks like:

```
Person     Case
John       A
John       B
Bill       C
David      F
```

I'd like to be able to transform it to the following structure:

```
Person  Case_1  Case_2 ... Case_n
John    A       B
Bill    C       NA
David   F       NA
```

My original thought was along the lines of:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Person) %>%
  spread()

Error: Please supply column name
```

What's the easiest, or most R-like way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first add a case id to the dataset, which can be done with a combination of `group_by` and `mutate`:

```
dat = data.frame(Person = c('John', 'John', 'Bill', 'David'), Case = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'F'))
dat = dat %>% group_by(Person) %>% mutate(id = sprintf('Case_%d', row_number()))
dat %>% head()
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  Person   Case     id
  <fctr> <fctr>  <chr>
1   John      A Case_1
2   John      B Case_2
3   Bill      C Case_1
4  David      F Case_1
```

Now you can use `spread` to transform the data:

```
dat %>% spread(Person, Case)
# A tibble: 2 × 4
      id   Bill  David   John
*  <chr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1 Case_1      C      F      A
2 Case_2     NA     NA      B
```

You can get the structure you list above using:

```
res = dat %>% spread(Person, Case) %>% select(-id) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
names(res) = unique(dat$id)
res
      Case_1 Case_2
Bill       C   <NA>
David      F   <NA>
John       A      B
```

Comment: No need for `ungroup`, and your mutation can be made easier with builtins: `mutate(ID = row_number())`.

Comment: Really helpful answer, Paul. I've learned most of my wrangling in Pandas, and couldn't for the life of me work out how to do the same thing in R. Now also know the t() function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I feared that the spread would abide by the `group_by`, but hadn't tested it. I also did not know of `row_number`. Always something new to learn in the hadleyverse. I updated my answer.

Comment: @elksie5000 no problem! Pandas is really cool :). Maybe have a look at a [`dplyr` tutorial I wrote](http://stcorp.nl/R_course/tutorial_dplyr.html) to get the general idea of `dplyr` down.

Comment: If you do `spread(Case, Person)`, is it still necessary to transpose the data frame afterwards ?

Comment: @FlorianGD when using `spread(Case, Person)` you get a totally different outcome, i.e. per case ID and case letter who is involved. This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: My bad, I couldn't check when I commented. What I meant was that if you do `dat %>% spread(id, Case)` you do not have to process it further: the Person is in the first column, you do not have to transpose and the result is a dataframe.